# Please help me guess this hybridAuth code

Tags: php, hybridauth

Can somebody help me guess out this code..this is just a snippet and  I think I included all the codes needed for my question. Actually this code is from hybridAuth. My question is, where does "user_id" from the last line came from? I wanted to know because $_SESSION["user"] gives the value of the "id". And I wanted to make another $_SESSION[" "] where I can place the value of email-add from the database (same location where that user_id's "id" exist)

```
// create an instance for Hybridauth with the configuration file path as parameter
$hybridauth = new Hybrid_Auth( $hybridauth_config );

// try to authenticate the selected $provider
$adapter = $hybridauth->authenticate( $provider );

// grab the user profile
$user_profile = $adapter->getUserProfile();

// load user and authentication models, we will need them...
$authentication = $this->loadModel( "authentication" );
$user = $this->loadModel( "user" );

# 1 - check if user already have authenticated using this provider before
$authentication_info = $authentication->find_by_provider_uid( $provider, $user_profile->identifier );

# 2 - if authentication exists in the database, then we set the user as connected and redirect him to his profile page
if( $authentication_info ){
// 2.1 - store user_id in session
$_SESSION["user"] = $authentication_info["user_id"];
```

Comment: @Michael if I type var_dump($authentication_info) will it display on monitor? no need for echo?

Comment: I expanded it into an answer below.  No need for echo - [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) is a debugging function which will display the contents of an array or object. Not used for real display output, just for debugging and visualization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `$authentication->find_by_provider_uid()` returns an associative array, one key of which is `user_id`.

To see what other columns are returned by that call:

```
var_dump($authentication_info);
```

If the `email` is among the keys in that array, you may then set it in `$_SESSION`:

```
// Store the email into session if it is present in $authentication_info
// Use whatever the appropriate key you find, be it email, email_address, user_email, whatever...
$_SESSION['user_email'] = $authentication_info['email'];
```

Comment: if var_dump($authentication_info); won't show on display, then how can I view its other content?

Comment: You can still try print_r($authentication_info).

Comment: @IvorySantos `var_dump()` will show on your display.  If you don't see it in the webpage output for some reason, view the page source and you will see it there.